# Trouble setting Bitmap to ParseImageView?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview, parse-platform

I am having trouble setting the Bitmap to the ParseImageView that I have inside one of my layouts. I am also having trouble saving the Bitmap as a ParseFile to ParseDB and I believe it is because the data isn't being returned properly on OnActivityResult();

**Anyone know if I am properly retrieving the bitmap data after the user picks a picture and crops/saves?**

```
public class UserActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

Context context;
public ParseImageView ivProfilePic;
private TextView tvUserName, tvBio, tvTagLine;

private static final String TAG = "OwlSample";
private static final int RESULT_OK = 0;
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 888;

final int PHOTO_WIDTH = 500;
final int PHOTO_HEIGHT = 500;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {
        // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
        // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist. The fragment
        // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
        // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
        // won't be displayed. Note this is not needed -- we could
        // just run the code below, where we would create and return
        // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
        return null;
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.activity_user_fragment, container, false);

    Button logoutButton = (Button) mLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.log_out_button);
    logoutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button editProfileButton = (Button) mLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.btn_editProfile);
    editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageButton btnFindFriends = (ImageButton) mLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.btn_friends);
    btnFindFriends.setOnClickListener(this);

    tvUserName = (TextView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
    tvBio = (TextView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_bio);
    tvTagLine = (TextView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_tagline);
    ivProfilePic = (ParseImageView) mLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.imageViewUserProfile);

    ivProfilePic.setOnClickListener(this);

    updateViewsWithProfileInfo();
    return mLayout;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        // Check if the user is currently logged
        // and show any cached content
        updateViewsWithProfileInfo();
    } else {
        // If the user is not logged in, go to the
        // activity showing the login view.
        showLoginActivity();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.log_out_button:
        Log.e(TAG, "Tapped sign out");
        onLogoutButtonClicked();
        break;

    case R.id.btn_editProfile:
        Log.e(TAG, "Tapped editProfile button");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditProfileActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    case R.id.btn_friends:
        Log.e(TAG, "Tapped editProfile button");

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(),
                FriendSearchActivity.class);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent1);
        break;

    case R.id.imageViewUserProfile:

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        intent2.setType("image/*");
        intent2.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent2.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent2.putExtra("outputX", PHOTO_WIDTH);
        intent2.putExtra("outputY", PHOTO_HEIGHT);
        intent2.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent2.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent2.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent2, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

    }

}

private void showLoginActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void onLogoutButtonClicked() {
    // Log the user out
    ParseUser.logOut();

    // Go to the login view
    showLoginActivity();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) {
        final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {

            final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

            Bitmap bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
            ivProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] data1 = stream.toByteArray();

            final ParseFile profilePicture = new ParseFile(
                    "profilePicture", data1);
            profilePicture.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e != null) {

                    } else {

                        currentUser.put("photo", profilePicture);
                        currentUser.saveInBackground();
                        updateViewsWithProfileInfo();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
}

private void updateViewsWithProfileInfo() {
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser.getString("displayName") != null) {
        tvUserName.setText(currentUser.getString("displayName"));
    } else {
        tvUserName.setText("");
    }

    if (currentUser.getString("bio") != null) {
        tvBio.setText(currentUser.getString("bio"));
    } else {
        tvBio.setText("");
    }

    if (currentUser.getString("tagline") != null) {
        tvTagLine.setText(currentUser.getString("tagline"));
    } else {
        tvTagLine.setText("");
    }

    ParseFile imageFile = currentUser.getParseFile("photo");
    if (imageFile != null) {
        ivProfilePic.setParseFile(imageFile);
        ivProfilePic.loadInBackground();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

to save a bitmap to parse as a file upload...

get either the files bytes or the bitmap's bytes into a byteArray and wrap the array in the body of a POST to parse.

Then, use the Name & URL included in the response from the parse file upload to make a pointer/relation to the file as an element in another class. When u want to load the bitmap to a view, you use the relation to the URL to supply to some framework that handles photo loading.

example :

```
  final Uri uri = Uri.parse(arg);
  final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  Runnable myrun =  new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            try {
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                        getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri),null,options);
```

Comment: Do you believe that I am retrieving the bitmap properly? I create a Byte[] with the bitmap, and do what is necessary to create a ParseFile following the documentation already. -- Bitmap bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data"); -- Does this line look correct?

Comment: why do u need parcelable? just pass the string of the URL that points to the photo u uploaded. Then use a decoder to get a bitmap OR use a framework for loading photos so u just pass the url & imageView to the framework

Comment: I will look into how to get the String URL for the image that is created.